# Yii2 & Codeception - Enabling tester module in unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, yii2, codeception

I use Yii2 and build-in codeception and want to write unit tests. In the documentation of codeception I´ve found this example test:

```
function testUserCanBeActivatedWithValidKey()
{
    // lookup for user with Eloquent API
    $user = User::find($this->user_id);
    // executing action
    $isActivated = $user->activate('123456'));
    // performing assertion
    $this->assertTrue($isActivated);
    // checking that data was actually saved into database
    $this->tester->seeRecord('users', [
        'id' => $this->user_id,
        'is_active' => 1
     ]);
}
```

But when I´m trying to write the test myself, there is no `$this->tester` Object. How can I benefit from methods like `seeInDatabase()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function testUserCanBeActivatedWithValidKey(WebGuy $I)
{
    // lookup for user with Eloquent API
    $user = User::find($this->user_id);
    // executing action
    $isActivated = $user->activate('123456'));
    // performing assertion
    $this->assertTrue($isActivated);
    // checking that data was actually saved into database
    $I->seeRecord('users', [
        'id' => $this->user_id,
        'is_active' => 1
     ]);
}
```

You get the tester object as a param from the test function. If it's a TestGuy, a WebGuy or something else, you have to look in your codeception.yml configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserTest extends \yii\codeception\TestCase
{
   /**
    * @var \CodeGuy
    */
    protected $tester;

function testUserCanBeActivatedWithValidKey()
{
    // lookup for user with Eloquent API
    $user = User::find($this->user_id);
    // executing action
    $isActivated = $user->activate('123456'));
    // performing assertion
    $this->assertTrue($isActivated);
    // checking that data was actually saved into database
    $this->tester->seeRecord('users', [
        'id' => $this->user_id,
        'is_active' => 1
     ]);
}
```

Override $tester and start using it.